# Initializing and Using Camel without Spring

Tags: apache-camel

I trying to understand the 'camel without spring' tutorial and I am not entirely sure what the 'JndiCamelServletContextListener' class is doing. Is it initializing the camel context and adding the routing information to it? Is there any way I can access the created Camel Context from other parts of my application like a EJB?

http://camel.apache.org/servlet-tomcat-no-spring-example.html

My idea was to add a Servlet context listener and in the contextInitialized method, I would create a Camel context and save it in the Servlet context as an attribute. Then, I would be able to get the camel context any where in the application if needed.

Is there a way to achieve this using the example mentioned.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Good idea to store the created `CamelContext` as an attribute on the `ServletContext`. I have logged a ticket to get this implemented in the next release

- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-7711

Comment: Thanks for the response. So is there a way to access the created CamelContext in my application if I initialize it in the way shown in the example? I want to use that to add routes programmatically(java dsl) if needed.